# How to target directory above with pattern glob

Tags: globbing

How can i create a pattern for directories that are one level above?

Say i'm in `/dir/server/` and i want to match `/dir/src/`?

I need to modify this glob: `'!{app.js,{src,common,lib}/**}'`  but eg. `'!{app.js,../{src,common,lib}/**}'` doesnt work, neither does `'!{app.js,{../src,../common,../lib}/**}'`.

I'm trying to get [this](https://gist.github.com/dillonkrug/25ee1397510aa4dec1d7) `node forever` script to work for me.